# How do I include the static library for Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

According to the [Core Plot Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications):

> Core Plot is built as a static library
>   for iPhone, so you'll need to drag the
>   libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a static
>   library from under the
>   CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeproj group to
>   your target's Link Binary With
>   Libraries folder.

I do not see the mentioned library, where might it be?

Answer (score 3):

This is the location referred to in the integration instructions:
[image: Core Plot static library location]
<sub>(source: [sunsetlakesoftware.com](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/CorePlotStaticLibraryLocation.jpg))</sub>

This will show up as red until the library has been compiled, but you can still drag this library over to the `Link Binary With Libraries` build phase.  If you follow the remainder of the instructions for setting this as a dependency for your application target, it will be built before your application is.

In the future, framework-specific questions like this might receive faster answers on the [Core Plot mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/coreplot-discuss).